How to write heading along with paragraph after scrapping a website when all the heading are in one class and all the paragraphs are in other class?
I am trying to scrape this link using selenium -
https://library.municode.com/az/avondale/codes/code_of_ordinances?nodeId=CD_ORD_CH1GEPR
for practice. But I am not able to write paragraphs specific to its title in my document.
Looping is not working as it writes one heading and all the paragraphs on page then another heading and again all the paragraphs.
I tried this.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

website= "https://library.municode.com/az/avondale/codes/code_of_ordinances?nodeId=CD_ORD_CH1GEPR"

#setting up driver
driver_path="path\chromedriver\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe"
Service = webdriver.ChromeService(executable_path = driver_path)
driver=webdriver.Chrome(service=Service)

document_path="path\\documents"

#Running website
while True:    
    driver.get(website)
    driver.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(10)

    #Each title-paragraph chunk
    chunks=driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"chunks")
    for chunk in chunks:
        titles=chunk.find_elements(By.XPATH,'.//div[@class="chunk-title"]')
        paras=chunk.find_elements(By.XPATH,'.//p')
    for title in titles:
        print(title.text+"\n")
        for para in paras:
            print(para.text+"\n")
    '''
    #writing in document
    with open(f"{document_path}\\document.txt",'w') as document:
        for title in titles:
            document.writelines(title.text+' '+"\n")
            for para in paras:
                document.write(para.text+' '+"\n")
'''
    #closing
    close=input()
    if close=="x":
        driver.quit()
        break

I want this:-
title 1

paragraph 1

paragraph 1.2

title 2

paragraph 2

But I am getting this:-

title 1

paragraph 1

paragraph 1.2

paragraph 2

title 2

pragraph 1

paragraph 1.2

paragraph 2

the html is something like this-
<div class="chunk-title">Article I - GENERAL PROVISIONS</div>

for all titles.
and
<div class="chunk-content">
    <p class="p0">
           The ordinances embraced in the following chapters and sections shall constitute and
           be designated "Avondale City Code, Revised, 1984" and may be so cited. Such code may
           also be cited as the "Avondale City Code." (Code 1971, Art. 1-1)
    </p>
</div>

for all paragraphs.
Can multithreading work here?

you have wrong indentations in code. You should have for title in titles: inside for chunk in chunks:. And the same problem is with writing to file - you should put all for chunk in chunks: inside while open(...) as ...

when you assign variable = or check it == then use spaces around = and == to make code more readable. See more: PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code

all problem is (By.CLASS_NAME,"chunks") which gives you wrong elements. You should start with (By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".chunks li")

A few suggestions...

As of Selenium 4.6, you no longer need to setup and configure the drivers. They added SeleniumManager and it takes care of downloading, configuring, and using the appropriate driver automatically. I removed all the unnecessary code that you had.

If all you're trying to do is dump the entirety of the text on the page, there's no real point in iterating through all of the subelements and printing each one. Just grab the highest level element containing what you want and dump element.text. Done.

Threading is not needed here.


With this in mind, here's the working code...
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

website = "https://library.municode.com/az/avondale/codes/code_of_ordinances?nodeId=CD_ORD_CH1GEPR"

#setting up driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

#running website
driver.get(website)
driver.maximize_window()

#print text
chunks = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"ul.chunks")
print(chunks.text)


All problem is (By.CLASS_NAME,"chunks") which gives you wrong elements.
And later it finds the same titles and paragraphs many times.
You should start with ie. (By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".chunks li")

Minimal working code which I used for tests. It also writes in file.
import os
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

website = "https://library.municode.com/az/avondale/codes/code_of_ordinances?nodeId=CD_ORD_CH1GEPR"

#setting up driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

#document_path = os.path.join('path', 'documents')
document_path = '.'

driver.get(website)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(10)

fullpath = os.path.join(document_path, 'document.txt') 
with open(fullpath, 'w') as document:

    # Each title-paragraph chunk
    #chunks = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "chunks")  # wrong  
    #chunks = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.chunks")  # wrong if you use another for-loops
    chunks = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".chunks li")  # OK
    for chunk in chunks:
        titles = chunk.find_elements(By.XPATH, './/div[@class="chunk-title"]')
        paras = chunk.find_elements(By.XPATH, './/p')
        for title in titles:
            print(f'title: {title.text}')
            document.write(f'title: {title.text}\n')
            #document.write(f'{title.text}\n')
            for para in paras:
                print(f'  para: {para.text}')
                document.write(f'  para: {para.text}\n')
                #document.write(f'{para.text}\n')

input('Press ENTER to close')

